# wrapping a gradle project with maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I want to wrap an existing gradle project (build.gradle) to also have a pom.xml file such that the following gradle tasks will be invoked when we invoke maven:

- 'maven install' -> invoke 'gradle build'
- 'maven clean' -> invoke 'gradle clean'
- 'maven clean install -DskipTests' -> invoke 'gradle clean build -x tests'

So my question is:
Is there a way to create a pom.xml that I can customize (and override) what 'install', 'clean' do? Additionally, Can I have access to the flags that were passed to maven so that I can rewrite them as the flags I want to pass to gradle?

The ultimate goal is to include this project inside a larger multi project where all projects are maven based and we can automate everything based on maven commands.

Comment: Having multiple build systems for each sub-project might cause greater costs longer term (things falling out of sync, misconfigurations, etc). I'd suggest migrating to a single build system for the entire project.

Comment: Good point, we are aware of this. This is only for a faster development process. Gradle will still be used in our pipeline and in our CI/CD

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's no way to configure Maven to achieve this, since you're trying to override default plugins. That said, you might get some results by aliasing `mvn` to point to a script which replaces the parameters to equivalent Gradle calls: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html. The downside to this approach is that you'd need to configure this alias on every system that invokes Maven/Gradle on this project. That said: I must strongly urge you to reconsider doing this. Pick either Maven or Gradle and stick with it.

Comment: If you already have Maven based why trying to override from Gradle? Why not 100% Maven? And no you wont be able to override this way...

Answer (score 0):

If the `build.gradle` is not to complicated, I would just rewrite it as pom. If you do not want to do that, one could have a closer look at the commands you mentioned:

- AFAIK, `mvn clean` and `gradle clean` do the same, so no need to worry.
- calling `gradle build` when starting `mvn install` can probably be achieved by using the gradle-maven-plugin (https://github.com/LendingClub/gradle-maven-plugin).
- Sending the `skipTests` parameter to gradle can probably also achieved through the gradle-maven-plugin.